# can't edit google's TicTacToeSample bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded this Google's xcode sample project "TicTacToeSample" and part of Google's example instructions is to change the bundle identifier field that was pre-filled with "TicTacToeSample." How do I remove the greyed out text and place my own bundle identifier per Google's instructions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the folder the xcode project directory is located in. Open the .plist file for the project. Change the 'Bundle identifier' to whatever you want it to. Go back to your xcode and close and re-open your project the new bundle identifier will be there and you will be able to change it again if you want to from xcode.